# No sound on videos

Tags: iphone

I dropped my iphone3 in the water I turned the power off, and dried it in rice for 3 days slowly almost everything became functional again except I have no sound when I watch videos.

Comment: Could you clarify the point of your question? It sounds like a hardware failure.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely likely the water has permanently damaged the circuitry, but you might power it off and set it on a shelf for a week to ensure it has dried completely.

Also, you can test sound with headphones to see if it is just the speaker.